# WPF MDI in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mdi

I am developing a system in WPF with Ribbons and want to use MDI, but I am not able to use the [dll's Codeplex](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/) and other research I did always lead me to the same place ...

Is there any alternative to MDI for Visual Studio 2012?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avalondock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) is quite simple to use and we can restyle it as well

Comment: In the documentation refers to .Net 4.0 (VS2010 and SharpDevelop 4).
 Will it work in .Net 4.5 (VS2012)?

Comment: I haven't tried in 4.5 but I think it should work